# Using sinon stub to mock data in mocha test case fro sails.js controller

Tags: sails.js, mocha.js, sinon, sinon-chai

I have one function in one of controller that calls another controller to get user session. How should I use sinon stub or sinon mock to mock the data so I can make sure the `Service.USER_ID != uID` under user controller.js

```
##
#user controller js
##

const limitConst = sails.config.globals.limitConst;

const checkuserID = function (uID, cb) {
  if (uID === Service.USER_ID) {
    return getUserPermission(cb);
  }
}

const getUserPermission = function (cb) {
  User.find({ select: ['id'], where: { enabled: 1 } }).limit(limitConst).exec(function (err, memberIds) {
      return cb(null, memberIds);
    });
  });
};

##
#Service controller js
##
const USER_ID = 0;
const getUserPermission = function (session) {
  return _.get(session, 'user.id', USER_ID);
};

##
#test case js
##
it('Should get session.', function (done) {
    request(sails.hooks.http.app)
    .get('user/getuserpermission')
    .set('Authorization', 'oasis')
    .send('Accept', 'application/json')
    .send(data)
    .end(function (err, res) {
      done();
    });
});
```